# LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `,'

Tags: floats

I am working with texshop on Mac and because of an upgrade to El Capitan,
I had to reinstall tex live. Now I have a problem with older files where
figures are inserted. I get the message

LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `,'.

I do not even know what this is, let alone how to fix it. The figure does
appear, but is there something else in another place in the file that
went wrong? I am typesetting a whole book and this problems appears with
some, but not all of the figures.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You have some `\begin{figure][...]` where you have a `,` in the optional argument. This is not an allowed option for floats like `figure` – hence the message. In earlier versions on LaTeX unknown float options have been ignored but the new version leads to the error you experience.

Comment: It seems that the problematic floats have `\begin{figure}[,]` either provide a valid float positioning specifier , such as for example `\begin{figure}[tp]` or none at all `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`

Answer (score 3):

You have something like

```
\begin{figure}[t,b]
```

which was always an error but in older latex releases silently ignored

Now it generates an error that `,` is not known, and should be deleted.

the worst case was if you had

```
\begin{figure}[,]
```

as previously this would not generate an error but it prevents the float being placed *anywhere* until it is flushed out at the end of the document or by `\clearpage`